# Extract a sample from RAW audio file on Android

Tags: android, audio, sampling

I have an android application that records AUDIO in raw format
how can i extract a sample of the recording?
for example if the raw file has 3 minutes of audio recorded, i would like to extract 20 seconds of the contents from an arbitrary start position
is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file contains interleaved PCM data with no header and you know the properties of the audio data (sample rate, number of channels, etc) the problem can be solved with basic math:

The number of bytes of audio data per second is `sampleRate * bytesPerSample * numChannels`.

The starting offset in bytes would be then be `bytesPerSecond * offsetInSeconds`, and the size of the chunk to read (in bytes) would be `bytesPerSecond * lengthInSeconds`.

Comment: Michael, thanks for your answer, i will know the sample rate and number of channels, where would i source bytes per sample from? is this bytes i require in my extracted file or the original full recording?

Comment: I assume that you specified whether to use 8 or 16 bits per sample when you created your recorder. The number of bytes per sample is just the bitdepth divided by 8.

Comment: i am using 16 bit. Should have mentioned i am recording .WAV format files. Thanks again.